# Cancel pending notification messages in Firebase

Tags: android, .net, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using firebase in a web project where have .net as our backend, and we send push notifications using firebase cloud messaging to our users' android and IOS devices.

When sending notifications to firebase and the user device is offline, the notifications can't be delivered and the notification status will be pending according to firebase documentation.

I want to know if there is a way we can cancel these pending notifications and stop them midway to the user's devices.

Comment: Once a message has been sent, there is no way to cancel its delivery. See the questions I linked and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+cancel+push+notification